# How fast $P\big( \text{Poisson}(\lambda_n) \leq u_n \big)$ converges to $0$ when $u_n \ll \lambda_n$?

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, large-deviation-theory

Let $X_n \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_n)$, with $\lambda_n \to \infty$, $u_n$ such that $u_n \to \infty$, and $p_n := P\big( X_n \leq u_n \big)$.

I'm pretty sure that if $\lambda_n \sim u_n$ or $\lambda_n \ll u_n$, then $p_n\to 1$, eventhough I can't prove it. Any hint/proof is welcome.

Also I think that $u_n \ll \lambda_n$ implies $p_n \to 0$, so my next question is : how to prove it ? and how fast does this convergence occur ?

Comment: By Tchebychev, i only came up with $P_n < \frac{1}{z_n}$. Is there a better bound ?

Comment: Assume that $X_k$ is Poisson$(k)$, then the law of large numbers yields $P(X_k\leqslant xk)\to1$ if $x>1$ and $P(X_k\leqslant xk)\to0$ if $x<1$. Thus, if $$\limsup\frac{u_n}{\lambda_n}<1$$ then $$P(\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda_n)\leqslant u_n)\to0$$ and, if $$\liminf\frac{u_n}{\lambda_n}>1$$ then $$P(\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda_n)\leqslant u_n)\to1$$ Both convergence are exponential, that is, the error is controlled by $e^{-c\lambda_n}$ for some positive $c$, as elementary large deviations principles show.

Comment: @Did thank you ! Actually, i'm really interested in this error control. But unfortunately, i don't know anything about LDP. How come does this estimates appear ?

Comment: Note that, for each fixed $x<1$ and $t>0$, $$P(X_k\leqslant xk)\leqslant e^{xtk}E(e^{-tX_1})^k=e^{ka(t)}$$ with $$a(t)=xt+\log E(e^{-tX_1})$$ Choosing $t_x=-\ln x$ yields $$a(t_x)=x-x\ln x-1<0$$ hence the exponential control.

Comment: @Did Thank you once again :)